# How to Override/Modify template of 'node_module' package?

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance, components, node-modules

I'm working with angular2 project. And I have some components(ex. header, footer, etc) which I want to reuse in another project with some changes. for that I've created node packages and import that packages in new project.
But my problem is, I want some changes according to new project in that inbuilt node package template. I found the way to modify css but failed to change any content of template.

Here is the component code which extends node package

**about.component.ts**

```
import {Component , ViewChild, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FaqComponent } from 'FaqComponent';

@Component({
  selector: 'about',
  styleUrls: [ './about.component.scss' ],
  templateUrl: './about.component.html'
})
export class AboutComponent extends FaqComponent {}
```

here, FaqComponent is a node package. and as about component extends that, FaqComponent's templates override AboutComponent's template. and I want to apply changes in template of that FaqComponent.

How can I do it? Is there any way?
Any help would be appreciated.